# Analytical solution of quadratic programming when $H$ is not p.d.?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Considering the unconstrained quadratic programming: $$\min_x \frac{1}{2}x^\top Hx+c^\top x$$ 
if $H$ is not positive definite, can we still calculate the analytical solution?

Comment: If $H$ is not positive definite, then there is no solution, since there is no minimum.

Comment: yes, you are right on that! thanks

Comment: However, when $H$ is positive semidefinite, but not positive definite, the problem may (or may not) have a solution depending on $H$ and $c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We consider the function 
$$ f \colon \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^n \to \R, \quad x \mapsto \frac 12 x^tHx + c^t x $$ 
for $H\in \def\M{\mathrm{Mat}}\M_n(\R)$, $c \in \R^n$. Taking derivatives gives 
\begin{align*}
  f'(x)h &= \frac 12 x^t(H+H^t)h + c^t h\\
  f''(x)[h,k] &= \frac 12 h^t(H+H^t)k
\end{align*}
So we see that the critical points of $f$ are the solutions of 
$$ \frac 12(H + H^t)x = c$$
which are minima iff $\frac 12(H+H^t)$ is positive semi-definite.